# Locating Libraries

Tags: java, jna

I am playing with JNA on Mac OS X and Linux. My question is if i am looking for a function "if_nametoindex" how to figure out which library to load? Most of the example i could find concentrate on Windows and they load "kernel32".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Leopard Mac `man 3 if_nametoindex` says:

```
LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)
```

Obviously that's a 'manual' rather than an automated approach...

Comment: I should have RTFM, i used man pages from google and never bothered to use man.